Is there racial bias in police shootings in America?
On Triggernometry show Roland G. Fryer Jr. makes the claim

I thought I was going to be able to show that the police were biased very easily, and then we gathered literally millions
and millions of data points on lethal use of force. what we found was Zero racial differences and that is the part that made people really really upset

He seems to refer to paper 'An Empirical Analysis of Racial Differences in Police Use of Force'. In which he writes:

VI. Interpretation
A number of stylized facts emerge from the analysis of the preceding sections. On non-lethal uses of force, there are racial differences – sometimes quite large – in police use of force, even after controlling for a large set of controls designed to account for important contextual and behavioral factors at the time of the police-civilian interaction. As the intensity of use of force increases from putting hands on a civilian to striking them with a baton, the overall probability of such an incident occurring decreases but the racial difference remains roughly constant. On the most extreme uses of force, however – ocer-involved shootings with a Taser or lethal weapon – there are no racial differences in either the raw data or when accounting for controls.

On Harvard blog Justin M. Feldman makes the opposite claim:

There is racial bias in shootings by police

Is there evidence for racial bias in police shootings in America when accounting for controls?

"when accounting for controls" is a big methodological choice. If (plausible but I have no proof) African-American are more at risk of being controled and if (plausible but I have no proof) the risk of being shot given that one is controled is equal across racial groups, then the answer to your question would be "no" but the risk of being shot would be higher for A-A than for the general population.

@Evargalo That is part of the claim so I had to include it.

@Evargalo You comment gives the impression that you don't understand what the word "controls" means in the context of statistics.

@Acccumulation : then my comment gives a false impression of this statistician who deals with controls all the time.

@Evargalo In the context of statistics, the entire dataset is controlled. Individual observations aren't controlled, and certainly people are not controlled.

Is being controlled a control variable?

@Evargalo That's not standard English syntax. Also, per WP, "A control variable (or scientific constant) in scientific experimentation is an experimental element which is constant (controlled) and unchanged throughout the course of the investigation." So 1. Race is not a control variable, since it varies across observations. 2. Even if race were a control variable, it would not be correct to say that Black people are controlled. You control the variable, not people with a particular value of that variable.

@Acccumulation: I suppose you missed the pun between "being controlled" (by the police) and "being a control variable" (for the data analyst). I won't try to use humor anymore.

I don't think the question is well defined. What constitutes "bias"? Should we expect, for example, in an "unbiased" condition, that police shootings are even across races per capita of the entire population, or instead that they are proportionate to numbers of those of each race committing violent crimes (or some other criteria)? A priori, do we consider the possibility that this would make a difference? Where there is evidence of a disparity in the observed rate of violent crime (as in Xirui Zhao's answer), is that evidence of an actual disparity, or evidence of "bias" in observation?

Separately: we might consider whether the race of the officer impacts on any of these statistical correlations when it comes to police use of force. If it doesn't, then any racial disparity in outcomes seems thereby less likely to be a result of anything that could be called an unfair prejudice on the part of the officers.

@KarlKnechtel That sounds like a reasonable supposition, but evidence is to the contrary: https://www.openaccessgovernment.org/anti-black-bias/97383/ Black police displayed a higher explicitly pro-white or anti-Black bias [than black civillians].

@PaulJohnson my argument does not depend on comparing black police to black civilians. It depends on comparing black police to white police.


Is there racial bias in police shootings in America?

This is a loaded question (pun intended) because different people will interpret the question differently. At what levels of policing does racial bias occur? And at which of those levels (if any) is racial bias a problem? 538 actually wrote an article about this very issue.
Fryer's finding

On the most extreme uses of force, ...there are no racial differences in either the raw data or when accounting for controls.

This finding could be rephrased as "after the police has identified a person as a suspect, the police use extreme force at an equal rate between black and white suspects." This suggests that "suspects" do not experience racial discrimination. Based on the data recorded, this is true.
Systemic Racial Bias
But that is not the only way to define racial discrimination. The other factor is the rate that suspects are correctly identified for each racial group. Or to put it another way, how accurately do the police label people from different racial groups as "suspects"? If there is bias among the police force in treating black people as "suspects" at disproportionally high rate, then you'd expect more black people to experience extreme force as a proportion of the total population (not just the "suspect" population).
This infographic from the 538 article explains this very well:

Transcription:

How numbers that appear equitable can obscure bias
Let's say a police officer is patrolling the street, looking for people with contraband. The officer sees 100 people, some of whom have contraband on their person. Say the crowd is evenly split between Black and white people.
SCENARIO 1
The police officer stops 20 people, pulling aside equal numbers of Black and white people
Of the 20 people stopped, the officer uses force against 8 of them
The police officer used force against stopped white people and stopped Black people at the same rate: 40%.
But that's not the only scenario that can lead to that 40% number.
SCENARIO 2
This time, of the 100 people the officer sees, he stops 50. But this time he is biased in whom he pulls aside.
The officer uses force against 20 people this time.
This time, like last time, the police officer used force against stopped white people and stopped Black people at the same rate: 40%.
ANALYSIS
Things might appear equal, but in the second scenario, more Black people were stopped by the police than white people.
While use of force among stopped people is equal, use of force among all observed people is not:

12/50 = 24% of Black people have force used against them
8/50 = 16% of white people have force used against them

CONCLUSION
This is why knowing how often police use force against people they've stopped is not enough information to know whether use of force is racially biased. In real life, we don't have data on everyone who was observed but not stopped, but we need that to know whether use of force is biased overall.

Conclusion
Basically, racial bias is complicated, and the data that is collected is not at a high enough level to say definitively that there is no racial bias. Police shootings get a lot of attention, but by then multiple police interactions have already happened, any number of which could be biased. It can be simultaneously true that officers treat "suspects" the same regardless of race while also treating "people" differently when it comes to classifying them as suspects. My intuition is that the police likely identifies people as suspects incorrectly, and that disparity leads the black Americans to experience police shootings as a disproportional (biased) rate as compared to white Americans, but we would need better data on the more mundane police interactions to know for sure.

I'm unfamiliar with 538. It seems to be part of ABC news, but beyond that it's question mark.

They started with statistics-based political forecasting, but expanded briefly to other analytics stuff, including sports forecasting. Then ABC acquired them.

Personal issues (i.e. allegations of sexual misconduct) aside, Fryer Jr. is a fairly respected scholar whose research is probably correct insofar as it goes, but I do have to wonder about his motives considering that he is going on provocateur shows like "Triggernometry" to focus on that part of it while ignoring the other factor that you mention, the likelihood of racial bias in whom police choose to interact with in the first place. While I hesitate to accuse him of dishonest argumentation, a lot of those who use his research certainly are.

After all, for non-police murders, no one is trying to figure out whether the murderers exhibited bias starting from the point that they chose a target. No one says "Sure, Dylan Roof attacked a majority-Black church, but once he was there, he would have killed anyone he saw, so how biased was he, really?" Only police get this benefit of the doubt, but that kind of begs the question, since it assumes their pre-homicide targeting to be unbiased and legitimate by default.

Your answer isn't satisfactory. Yet, I'll award the points. I'd hate for them to be lost.

This seems to be missing an important part which is population levels where one group represents a much lower percentage of the population and gets stopped at the same or higher rate then the group that represents more of the population.

@JoeW It also fails to account for differences in rates of criminality in varying populations, as shown in crime statistics. It also fails to take into account differences in behavior of different populations during police encouters. It also... and so on. It's a complex topic.


Accounting for contextual variables recorded by police officers who may have an incentive to distort the truth is problematic. Yet, whether or not we include controls does not alter the basic qualitative conclusions. And, to the extent that there are racial differences in underreporting of non-lethal use of force (and police are more likely to not report force used on blacks), our estimates may be a lower bound. Not reporting officer-involved shootings seems unlikely.
—  'An Empirical Analysis of Racial Differences in Police Use of Force', page 5, Roland G. Fryer, Jr

This is about controlling any bias that might affect the reporting of data.
Any such bias would reduce the values in the final result, not exaggerate them.

For non-lethal incidents, the actual differences in racial bias will be greater than what the data suggests (and those differences really are significant).

For lethal incidents, the data and the observed differences will be much more reliable (and those differences really are negligible).


I.e. according to this analysis, the result of race having no effect on fatal incidents highly corresponds to reality.
Justin M. Feldman's report though doesn't even contain the word "fatal".
Instead it uses "shot", a term that will include many non-fatal incidents, which the Fryer report agrees are racially biased.
Feldman seems to be using a straw-man argument against the truth.
Even the title of his report, "Roland Fryer is wrong: There is racial bias in shootings by police", itself contains the fallacy, incorrectly implying that Fryer claimed there wasn't bias in shootings.

"straw-man argument against the truth." A link to source of the truth would be useful.

If Feldman is talking about shootings, while Fryer is talking about deads, they can be both right at the same time. That's not the same thing as a strawman argument.

@Rekesoft. If they were two independent reports, I'd agree. But in this case Feldman's report is a specific disagreement targeted at Fryer's.  See my updated last paragraph.

The quote from Fryer says "Not reporting officer-involved shootings seems unlikely," but you summarize that there is likely underreporting of non-lethal but not lethal use of force.  Maybe that's from a different part of the paper, but since the answer is saying Feldman isn't comparing apples to apples it might be good to clarify this.  After all, shootings aren't always fatal and fatalities aren't always caused by shootings.

Justin M. Meldman says in his post

Properly interpreted, the actual result from Fryer’s analysis is that the racial disparity in arrest rates is larger than the racial disparity in police shootings. This is an unsurprising finding, and proves neither a lack of bias nor a lack of systematic discrimination.

The first sentence is a fair assessment of Fryer's study. However, his inference is wrong. Higher crime rates should lead to more shootings. It's frivolous to obsess over whether police encounters or shooting thresholds are biased - neither can be perfectly studied because of confounding and unobservable variables and the lack of detailed data.
Given that black people objectively commit more crimes proportionally (as validated by the National Crime Victimization Survey - which is not susceptible to police bias), any allegation of police bias that doesn't adequately control for differences in criminal behavior is worthless.
Edit: It seems plausible that whatever factor causing a person to commit a crime also causes them to have worse police encounter outcomes, e.g., a reckless disregard for human life, welfare and societal rules. Any study that doesn't control for this factor is therefore methodologically deficient.

Implicit bias studies, such as one cited by Justin M. Meldman (Racial Bias in the Decision to Shoot in a Multiethnic Context), is similarly hopeless because they do not control for criminal behavior and therefore finds bias in favor of Asians against whites.

This feels more like a critique of the claim than an answer. Black people proportionally commit more crime, but does that proportion match the proportion of people shot by police who are black? That's what we really want to know here.

(Btw, regarding your profile: if you want an answer to be undeleted, you can appeal on the associated Meta site, in this case Meta Stack Overflow, and explain why you believe the deletion was wrong.)

"It's frivolous to obsess over whether police encounters or shooting thresholds are biased - neither can be perfectly studied" That appears to be a political statement of values hiding as an objective one. I can trivially counter that is not frivolous to be concerned about societal ills, and to try to reduce them, even without perfect data. Now we are just arguing opinions, and not facts.

"any allegation of police bias that doesn't adequately control for differences in criminal behavior is worthless" You are attempting to argue "statistical discrimination", which Meldman addresses in his argument. Whether you agree with his position or not, it is insufficient to ignore it entirely.

"therefore finds bias in favor of Asians against whites" This appears to be an appeal to consequences fallacy.

@Oddthinking I'm not arguing for statistical discrimination. I'm saying whatever factor causing a person to commit a crime also causes them to have worse police encounter outcomes. That any difference in police encounter outcomes must control for that factor by controlling for crime rates.

@XiruiZhao: 1) How is that different from statistical discrimination? 2) Which study are you alleging doesn't control for that?

@Oddthinking 1) Because it's based on an individualized finding of reasonable suspicion of a crime or threat to officers that justified the police stop or use of force. These additional criminality-evincing facts could be race-neutral. For example because men are more aggressive and appear so, it's reasonable to use more force against them. That's not group-average-based statistical discrimination.

All of the studies finding bias don't control for crime rates. They assume suspects of all races behave identically and race was the only explanation for any difference in police treatment.


Correction: some studies do control for race-neutral factors, such as unarmed v armed: https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1111/1745-9133.12269 But their database (https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/investigations/police-shootings-database/) is not sufficiently nuanced. For example the second unarmed black suspect Cameron Ford had violent priors and guns in his house. The officer claimed he couldn't see Ford's hands when Ford was charging at him. Note that violent priors is also a race-neutral fact and arguably an individualized finding.

Re: 1 - That sounds like you are begging the question. Do police only use violence in a race-neutral way? That's what we are trying to find out. Re: 2 - That sounds like a rookie mistake for a paper to make. Do you have some references to some examples? Are you claiming Feldman is making this error, because I didn't see it.
